# If Variable is Blank Then No Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to do what the below pseuedo code infers:

```
WHERE 
CASE 
WHEN @test <> '' THEN Agent = @test
ELSE --no where clause 
END
```

What is the correct structure for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use OR:

```
select * from yourTable
where @test = '' OR Agent = @test
```

if @`test` coming with null value (instead of `''`), you must use:

```
select * from yourTable
where @test is null OR Agent = @test
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, but how is the DB engine working this?  I would assume since an "OR" is used, the query would return all results regardless of whether @test is blank or has an actual value.  I also noticed that query run time increased significantly with this as opposed to a WHERE clause with one criterion

Comment: You need to apply a criteria to the db,considering the value of *test*: if *test* has a value, filter (as a normal where), but if *test* hasn't a value, no where (as a normal select, no filter). So, what you are doing here, is using a where to check values with your *test* condition; but if your condition hasn't a value, you need to provide the normal select.. So checking against "" (or is null) is independient of the row's values, which means they will return all.  The OR clause check the criteria for a normal where, but if not, checks if have to return the normal select(sorry my bad english)

Comment: you may also want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810714/where-is-null-is-not-null-or-no-where-clause-depending-on-sql-server-parameter

Comment: Should be `@test = ''` not `@test = ""`