# If Variable is Blank Then No Where Clause [Multiple]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528875/if-variable-is-blank-then-no-where-clause) one

The only difference is I have `3 sql parameter` which I set default value as null,
and if user provides any of these values, they should be included in `where` clause 
here is the stored procedure:

```
 create procedure [dbo].[SearchCareer] 
@country int =null,
@state int =null,
@position int=null
as

begin 
 SELECT * FROM Careers  where  Location=@country and @state=@state and @position=@position
end
```

I have tried this approach:

```
begin 
 SELECT * FROM Careers  where 
        ((@position is null and Position is null)
     or (Position = @position)) and
        ((@country is null and Location is null)
     or (Location = @country)) and 
        ((@state is null and StateID is null)
     or (StateID = @state))
end
```

It works fine when user only enter position but wont work on other cases.

I know I can use `IF , ELSE IF` To check and then build my query, but I want to avoid that.

Comment: What you have going on here is known as a catch-all query. It is very common and if done incorrectly can be unbelievably awful for performance. Take a look at this article which explains how to handle the logic and the performance of this type of query. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: Are you sure you want to do `@country is null and Location is null` (and similar)? Normally you'd have a `(@prm is null OR colValue=@prm) and ...`

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for the link. In your opinion which is better that IF ,ELSE IF or this approach.My Table is not much big.. hardly it will have 10k-20k records.

Comment: The simpler approach is the concept you are going with here....but what you posted is not even close to accurate from a logic perspective. With a small table the performance is not likely to be a big problem.

Comment: @Shnugo I don't Know difference between `@country is null and Location is null` and `(@prm is null OR colValue=@prm)`... That's why I don't know which one to use..

Comment: @KanisXXX if your column can hold `NULL` values, you handle the `NULL` as a *real* value. So: If the parameter is null the column must be null as well. Otherwise the column must be of the same value as the parameter. In the second case you allow the user to let a parameter unset. If `NULL` is passed in, ignore it, otherwise compare the values... Clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably close to what you are thinking. If the table is large the performance of this type of approach can become problematic. I had to make some guesses here because you where doing things like checking to see if a variable was equal to the same variable.

```
SELECT * --You really should use only the columns you need instead of *
FROM Careers  
where (Location = @country OR @country is null)
and ([state] = @state OR @state is null)
and (position = @position or @position is null)
```

Answer (score -1):

This will do what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM Careers  where  case @country when is null THEN @country ELSE Location end=@country and case @state when is null THEN @state ELSE State end=@state and case @position when is null THEN @position ELSE Position end=@position
```

I assumed that two other fields are State and Position.

Comment: Can you please format your query to provide better readability? Also please tell us why and how this query helps to solve the problem.

Comment: This is not going to work as posted. It is full of syntax errors. You can't have "when is null" like that.