# Condition WHERE clauses inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, where-clause

I am working with a stored procedure where I want to add or remove WHERE clauses according to the values of a couple parameters.

This is what I've got so far:

```
WHERE 
   t.iDdPais = @iIdPais
   AND t.iIdRegion = @iIdRegion
   AND t.dtFecha BETWEEN @dtStart AND @dtEnd
```

BUT, if @iIdPais is 0 (which means ALL), I need to remove that clause from the WHERE statement, the same goes to @iIdRegion.

Comment: Do you care about performance of the query?

Comment: Potential duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810714/where-is-null-is-not-null-or-no-where-clause-depending-on-sql-server-parameter   (?)

Comment: If there's any duplicate its this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185638/optional-arguments-in-where-clause

Comment: @GordonLinoff as it is a query that will be executed now and then and the those tables are catalog-ish, I care more about the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the entire `SELECT` inside `IF` clause..

```
IF(@ildPais =0 AND @ildRegion =0)
SELECT <THE DATASET> FROM THE TABLE
WHERE 
   t.iDdPais = @iIdPais
   AND t.iIdRegion = @iIdRegion
   AND t.dtFecha BETWEEN @dtStart AND @dtEnd

ELSE 
SELECT <THE DATASET> FROM THE TABLE
--no where clause
```

Comment: It is alot better than the accepted answer which will have terrible performance.

Comment: @HLGEM I Dont know what RDBMS system you use, but I do that on sql server with tables tens of of millions of rows without too much prolem. These sort of queries will never be the fastest, but with the right indexing that sort of query will be just fine.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use normal boolean logic:

```
WHERE 
  (@iIdPaid = 0 OR t.iDdPais = @iIdPais)
  AND (@iIdRegion=0 OR t.iIdRegion = @iIdRegion)
  AND t.dtFecha BETWEEN @dtStart AND @dtEnd
```

Comment: Very elegant. Thanks!

Comment: Fine if the dataset is small but what if the table has a million rows? The two extra checks would happen a million times each then.